# More Pythonic way to loop through UpdateCursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, performance, code-review

I have several sets of fields to populate based on other fields. The code below works, but I am wondering if there is a more Pythonic way to march through the i,j pairs? (Actual fieldnames are not this simple.)

```
i = ['FieldA1', 'FieldB1', 'FieldC1', 'FieldD1']
j = ['FieldA2', 'FieldB2', 'FieldC2', 'FieldD2']

if len(i) != len(j):
    arcpy.AddMessage("Error - i & j are not the same length")
    sys.exit()

for n in range(len(i)):
    fields = [i[n], j[n]]
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(mySHP, fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            val = row[0]
            if float(val) == -999:
                row[1] = -999
            else:
                row[1] = float(val) / 100
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: There's no need to make N passes through the table. Include all your columns in the field list and iterate within the for.

Comment: not sure what you mean--how will that iterate pairwise? (i.e., 1st run is with ['FieldA1', 'FieldA2']; second run is with ['FieldB1', 'FieldB2']; etc.

Comment: How many rows are being updated? If it's less than 1000, it would be difficult to measure a difference; if it's more than 10 million, there might not be enough time to run a statistically relevant sample with your method before the next required OS patch reboot.

Comment: @Vince the dataset I did the run time tests on was about 200 pts; I used my code for other datasets up to about 1100 pts. I agree, performance doesn't matter for this case. Was just trying to use it as an opportunity to improve my Python syntax.

Comment: Pythonic-ness should not be a goal if it means unnecessary I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have working code I think that this is a question that would be more on-topic at the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://httpa://coderreview.stackexchange.com) than here.  However, the inclusion of ArcPy cursors may confuse that site so in this instance I will provide an answer.

I suspect that this code:

```
i = ['FieldA1', 'FieldB1', 'FieldC1', 'FieldD1']
j = ['FieldA2', 'FieldB2', 'FieldC2', 'FieldD2']
fields = i + j
halfNumFields = len(i)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(mySHP, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        for n in range(halfNumFields):
            if int(row[n]) == -999:
                row[n + halfNumFields] = -999
            else:
                row[n + halfNumFields] = float(row[n]) / 100
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

would run faster than yours:

```
i = ['FieldA1', 'FieldB1', 'FieldC1', 'FieldD1']
j = ['FieldA2', 'FieldB2', 'FieldC2', 'FieldD2']

for n in range(len(i)):
    fields = [i[n], j[n]]
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(mySHP, fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            val = row[0]
            if float(val) == -999:
                row[1] = -999
            else:
                row[1] = float(val) / 100
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Irrespective of whether it is more Pythonic or not, the way that I would become sure about whether it runs faster is by performance timing the two alternatives.

Comment: I have a suspicion that the 2nd would be slower... it calls updateRow more frequently and that is where I suspect the time is being taken. The first updates *all* the fields in the row *in memory* (fast) and then updates the whole row (slow) which commits to the feature class on disc with data handler and HDD access overhead.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the advice. I did some run time tests out of curiosity. There are a couple other processes running in the script, but I left everything the same and just swapped the above codes. Ran each 3x; they basically have the same run times...
PolyGeo's version times: 0:00:29.363000, 0:00:29.393000, 0:00:28.980000
// My version times: 0:00:28.489000, 0:00:29.463000, 0:00:28.614000